# Unable to connect to sambashare as user

Tags: macos, connection, samba

I am having trouble accessing my sambashare on a Mac (high sierra) I am able to see the shared folders, but when I got to access them, I'm getting "you don't have permission to access this". My smb.conf file looks somewhat like the following:

```
[global]
   workgroup = MY-WORKGROUP
   server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
   security = user
   map to guest = bad user     
   dns proxy = no

[_it_data]
   comment = IT data file share (only sudo users accessible)
   path = /home/serveradmin/sambashare/_it_data
   browseable = no
   guest ok = no
   read only = no
   available = yes
   writeable = yes
   valid users = @sudo
```

The user I'm accessing this with is in the sudo group and the sambashare group:

```
serveradmin@comp:~$ id user
uid=1015(user) gid=1000(serveradmin) groups=1000(serveradmin),27(sudo),116(sambashare)
serveradmin@comp:~$
```

However, as stated, when I try to access the share I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfTHD.png) (not able to embed images yet).

Question being, how can I successfully get my share to connect to my computer?

---

UPDATE:

I've been able to gather some more information regarding this. It seems that I'm able to connect successfully to the shares to view them:

```
user:~ admin$ smbutil view //user@10.0.1.57
Password for 10.0.1.57: 
Share                                           Type    Comments
-------------------------------
print$                                          Disk    Printer Drivers
approved-software                               Disk    Approved software file share
office                                          Disk    Office file share, accessible to everyone
property-management                             Disk    Property management file share
construction                                    Disk    Construction file share
sales                                           Disk    Sales file share
home                                            Disk    Home directories, save your cool stuff here
property-files                                  Disk    Property files share
marketing                                       Disk    Marketing files share
accounting-share                                Disk    Accounting file share
IPC$                                            Pipe    IPC Service (SERVER (Samba share))

11 shares listed
```

But when I try to connect directly to a share:

```
user:~ admin$ smbutil view //user@10.0.1.57/home
Password for 10.0.1.57: 
smbutil: share name doesn't exist: Permission denied
```

So this kind of changes my question to, why am I not able to connect directly to my shares?

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who is having the same issue. Move the shared folders into `/srv` and it'll work